# Is someone who wears a wedding ring perceived as a more responsible individual

Tags: interviewing, work-environment

I'm curious as to the perceptions of wearing a wedding ring in an interview and/or office setting.  While it is personal information that is not relevant to job performance, does wearing a wedding ring aide in first impressions, giving the illusion that the individual is responsible enough to have a marriage and that they have their life in order (even if it is not necessarily true)?

Comment: Is it? The presence or absense of a wedding ring has neaver crossed my mind though I do remember an interview where I noticed the (male) art directors nail varnish was chipped.

Comment: Actually, wearing a wedding rings is discouraged in workplaces where it will pose an unnecessary risk for yourself and your partner. One such high-risk job sector I'm aware of is mental health services in places with patients who are acting out. Since these kinds of places have high staff turnover it doesn't really matter if you have a ring that you wear or not.

Comment: I'd like to know how this is off topic and not a relevant question as it pertains to the workplace...

Comment: Hi Squeemish - could've been closed as off-topic or not constructive.  You can read more in [this section of the FAQ](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) and as always feel free to discuss your question in [meta] or [chat].

Comment: @squeemish - This is not really about the workplace.  It applies equally out of the workplace as it does in.  That makes it off topic. In order to bring it on topic you could rescope the question to just wear to an interview, or on the job in a specific job environment(ie hospital, factory, office building).

Comment: I've given many interviews for technical/engineering positions, and have never once looked to see if a candidate was wearing a wedding band or not.  Even if I had I certainly wouldn't equate being married or unmarried with being better or more responsible.  Of course that's just me, and other industries may have different standards and/or reasons why they might strongly prefer a married or unmarried candidate.  So YMMV.

Comment: At least there's *one* person willing to put up with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are all sorts of people recruiting a safe guess would be that you can find those who pay attention to such details. However, personally I haven't met a recruiter who would admit that they're doing that officially.

What's more, I believe that there are countries where it is forbidden to use such arguments explicitly in hiring process.

Another thing, of course, is what our biases and prejudices are, but few people are aware of them and even fewer are willing to admit.

From my experience as a recruiter in different organizations and different positions: I wouldn't make such connection (wedding ring -> more responsible person). It just doesn't work in our everyday lives, so why should we pretend it works in our workplaces?

By the way: if you want to look for something that most of the time changes people's lives, it is having a child. Either way, I neither ask about that nor does it influence my hiring decisions in any way.